# Immutable remove item from array from all elements in Map | Redux state

Tags: redux, immutability

I am facing some problems removing an items from an array from every element within a map in my Redux state.

Using the following structure

```
entities: {
 brands: (Map) {
   first: {
     ...props,
     strategists: [
       '1', '2'
     ]
   },
   second: {
     ...props,
     strategists: [
       '1', '2'
     ]
   }, ..
 }
}
```

This is the best I could do:

```
const newBrands = state
      .get('brands')
      .map(brand => brand.updateIn(['strategists'], strategists => strategists.filter(s => s !== id)))

return state.set(['brands'], newBrands)
```

I doesn't add up tho and I coudn't really find it online either.

Thanks

Comment: Hi! I attempted to answer your question and think I may have the solution. But I almost didn't even try to solve this question at first because of the vagueness of this line "`It doesn't add up tho`". In the future you probably want to be more specific: Did you get an error? (If so, what was the error?) Did you get an unexpected result? (If so, include the result and explain how it differs from what you expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not used Immutable.js before, but I played around with your code example and everything seems to work as expected up until the last line, where you're setting state using `state.set(['brands'], newBrands)` instead of `state.set('brands', newBrands);` Could that have been the issue? Otherwise the only change is that I assumed that the `first` and `second` should also be `Map`s, so if you got an error before then maybe that was also part of the problem.

I included the code just in case:

```js
const state = Immutable.Map({});
const original = Immutable.Map({
  first: Immutable.Map({
     someProp: 'someValue1',
     strategists: [
       '1', '2', '3'
     ]
   }),
   second: Immutable.Map({
     someProp: 'someValue2',
     strategists: [
       '1', '2', '3'
     ]
   })
});

const id ='2';

const brands = original
  .map(brand => 
    brand.updateIn(['strategists'], strategists => 
      strategists.filter(s => s !== id)
    )
  );

const newState = state.set('brands', brands);
console.log(
  newState.get('brands')
    .toString()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
```